# Live sync of Spark RDD from Cassandra table

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm looking for a way to keep a Spark RDD in sync with a Cassandra table. I know it is possible to load a full Cassandra table into an RDD as a one shot operation but would like to keep the RDD synchronized with updates happening to the Cassandra table.
This will allow to not reload the full table into Spark everytime I need to get fresh data into Spark (which can be long if the table is big). 
Any hint ?

Comment: After searching it looks like a RDD is immutable and thus could not been modified once it has been created. I suppose that a good way to achieve what I want is to use spark-streaming to update the RDD in live (in parallel of updating Cassandra).

Comment: have you tried "streaming dataframe" feature of spark 2.0 ??